$A$ and $B$ are real matrices. $A+iB$ is unitary if and only if .... ("Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.) What does the author want to say?
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.

Exercise 6. Let $A,B$ be real matrices of degree $n$. Show that $$A+iB\text{ is unitary }\Leftrightarrow\pmatrix{A&-B\\B&A}\text{ is orthogonal. }$$
An $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$ can be considered as a $2n$-dimensional vector space over the real number field $\mathbb{R}$. If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ form a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ then, obviously, $a_1,\dots,a_n,ia_1,\dots,ia_n$ form a basis over $\mathbb{R}$. (The converse is also true.) Furthermore, for a given unitary metric $(x,y)_u$ in $V$ we may define an inner product $(x,y)=\Re{(x,y)_u}$ and thus turn $V$ into a metric vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)_u$ then $a_1,\dots,a_n,ia_1,\dots,ia_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)$. (The converse is also true.) This is the significance of Exercise 6.

My solution to Exercise 6:

Let $A+iB$ be unitary.
Then, $I_n=(A+iB)(A^T-iB^T)=(AA^T+BB^T)+i(BA^T-AB^T)$.
So, $I_n=AA^T+BB^T$ and $BA^T-AB^T=O_n$.
This is equivalent to $\pmatrix{A&-B\\B&A}\pmatrix{A^T&B^T\\-B^T&A^T}=I_{2n}$.

I also proved the following fact:

Fact 1. For a given unitary metric $(x,y)_u$ in $V$ we may define an inner product $(x,y)=\Re{(x,y)_u}$ and thus turn $V$ into a metric vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)_u$ then $a_1,\dots,a_n,ia_1,\dots,ia_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)$. (The converse is also true.)

My proof of Fact 1:

Suppose that $a_1,\dots,a_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)_u$.
Then, $(a_i,a_j)=\Re(a_i,a_j)_u=\Re\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.
Then, $(ia_i,a_j)=\Re(ia_i,a_j)_u=\Re i(a_i,a_j)_u=\Re i\delta_{ij}=0$.
Then, $(ia_i,ia_j)=\Re(ia_i,ia_j)_u=\Re i\overline{i}(a_i,a_j)_u=\Re(a_i,a_j)_u=\Re\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$.
So, $a_1,\dots,a_n,ia_1,\dots,ia_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)$.
Suppose that $a_1,\dots,a_n,ia_1,\dots,ia_n$ constitute an orthonormal basis over $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to $(\,\,,\,\,)$.
Let $c+di:=(a_i,a_j)_u$.
Then, $\delta_{ij}=(a_i,a_j)=\Re(a_i,a_j)_u=c$.
Then, $0=(ia_i,a_j)=\Re(ia_i,a_j)_u=\Re i(a_i,a_j)_u=\Re(-d+ci)=-d$.
So, $d=0$.
So, $\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+0i=c+di=(a_i,a_j)_u$.

I think the author didn't write how Fact 1 relates to Exercise 6 clearly.
What is the relation between Fact 1 and Exercise 6?

I am having trouble making sense of the sentence "I think the author didn't write how Fact 1 relates to Exercise 6 clearly." Are you saying that the author did write about the relation between these facts but was unclear in doing so, or are you saying that the author did not write about the relation between these facts even though it's clear that some relation exists?

The author wrote "This is the significance of Exercise 6." (This sentence is from English translation of this book.) I translated the corresponding sentence in the original Japanese edition of this book by ChatGPT. The result was "This is the meaning of Exercise 6." I thought the author is saying Fact 1 explains why Exercise 6 holds.

I think I finally understand what the author wants to say.
Let $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$.
$A+iB$ is unitary if and only if $\pmatrix{a_{1j}+ib_{1j}\\a_{2j}+ib_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}+ib_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$.
By Fact 1, $\pmatrix{a_{1j}+ib_{1j}\\a_{2j}+ib_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}+ib_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $\pmatrix{a_{1j}+ib_{1j}\\a_{2j}+ib_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}+ib_{nj}}$ and $\pmatrix{-b_{1j}+ia_{1j}\\-b_{2j}+ia_{2j}\\\vdots\\-b_{nj}+ia_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\mathbb{C}^n\ni a:=\pmatrix{a_{1}+ib_{1}\\a_{2}+ib_{2}\\\vdots\\a_{n}+ib_{n}}$. ($\mathbb{C}^n$ is a real vector space.)
Let $\mathbb{C}^n\ni b:=\pmatrix{c_{1}+id_{1}\\c_{2}+id_{2}\\\vdots\\c_{n}+id_{n}}$. ($\mathbb{C}^n$ is a real vector space.)
Let $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\ni c:=\pmatrix{a_{1}\\a_{2}\\\vdots\\a_{n}\\b_{1}\\b_{2}\\\vdots\\b_{n}}$.
Let $\mathbb{R}^{2n}\ni d:=\pmatrix{c_{1}\\c_{2}\\\vdots\\c_{n}\\d_{1}\\d_{2}\\\vdots\\d_{n}}$.
Then, $\mathbb{C}^n\ni a\mapsto c\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is an isomorphism.
Then, $(a,b)=\Re(a,b)_u=\Re ((a_1+ib_1)(c_1-id_1)+\cdots+(a_n+ib_n)(c_n-id_n))=a_1c_1+b_1d_1+\cdots+a_nc_n+b_nd_n=(c,d)$.
So, the above isomorphism preserves inner products.
$\pmatrix{a_{1j}+ib_{1j}\\a_{2j}+ib_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}+ib_{nj}}$ and $\pmatrix{-b_{1j}+ia_{1j}\\-b_{2j}+ia_{2j}\\\vdots\\-b_{nj}+ia_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\pmatrix{a_{1j}\\a_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}\\b_{1j}\\b_{2j}\\\vdots\\b_{nj}}$ and $\pmatrix{-b_{1j}\\-b_{2j}\\\vdots\\-b_{nj}\\a_{1j}\\a_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.
$\pmatrix{a_{1j}\\a_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}\\b_{1j}\\b_{2j}\\\vdots\\b_{nj}}$ and $\pmatrix{-b_{1j}\\-b_{2j}\\\vdots\\-b_{nj}\\a_{1j}\\a_{2j}\\\vdots\\a_{nj}}$ constitute an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\pmatrix{A&-B\\B&A}$ is orthogonal.
